# temple policy for babies/young kids

Tags: rules, temples, children

are there any policies for bringing very young kids (14 month) to a temple/pagoda (stroller, clothes etc)? We

Comment: It has never been an issue in the various community sanghas I've attended. I think this question would be best asked directly to the sangha/temple you plan on visiting.

Comment: some are strict about footwear, I heard

Answer (score 1):

i don't know as my knowledge any temple have SPECIFIC rules for carrying babies.

but parents or other elders should caring them proper and suitable way.

Answer (score 0):

As for getting toward the path and letting go of what binds, good to try to let go of householders tasks, and leave home to be able to listen to the Dhamma, good householder.

As for certain 'demands', at large one would meet other householders even at monasteries, who usually follow their common pattern of behaviour demand of their societies. Generally there isn't much a policy in regard of such, but sure very thoughtfull if letting those train toward letting go of attachments, also and mainly toward the body not fall into possible faulty thought till lust and strong attachment.

What ever good householder is able to give or likes to hold on is householders merit, goodness, or demerits, selfishness. So a lot of opportunities to observe ones mind by doing merits. Nothing really to worry aside of own good conduct.

(As for South Asian: children, babies are usually everywhere on side, part with all their kind and care. Just some new conflicts wher woman take on usually mans task. Feeding child with breast as police-woman may cause lot of trouble, even if very flexible in 'natural' requirement of normal life)